# How to remove the prefix field from the checkout in 2.2

Tags: checkout, admin, uicomponent, magento2.2, input

How do I remove this prefix field from the checkout in Magento 2.2?

[image]

When Googling this it appears there used to be an admin setting that has since been moved/removed:

[image]

### Update - I don't have the Show Prefix option

[image]

Comment: You can set No from dropdown in Stores -> Configuration -> Customer -> Customer Configuration -> Name and Address Options.

Comment: I don't have that option @RakeshJesadiya - I've added a screenshot of the options I have

Comment: i am checking in 2.2.0

Answer (score 2):

**For the enterprise version of Magento:**

For those who comes here from google and do not seen corresponding field in the store configuration:

You can check the `Magento_CustomerCustomAttributes` module where the fields `street_lines, prefix_show, middlename_show, suffix_show, dob_show, taxvat_show, gender_show` are disabled in the file `magento/module-customer-custom-attributes/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`. With that module all this attributes with its settings available now in the:

> Stores > Attributes > Customer

and

> Stores > Attributes > Customer Address

[image: menu view]

There you can set up the attribute's visibility and another options:

[image: visibility options]

Then if you already set up prefix/suffix options in the `Name and Address Options`:

[image: name and address options / prefix options]

you will see the prefix as dropdown on the frontend (checkout):

[image: prefix dropdown in address form on checkout]

Comment: Thank you @Siarhey Uchukhlebau

Answer (score 0):

Login on admin panel go to  Stores -> Configuration -> Customer -> Customer Configuration

Change Prefix to no under the Name and Address options
[image: Stores -> Configuration]

[image: Customer -> Customer Configuration]

[image: Change the Prefix to no under the name and address options]

Comment: What version of Magento are you on? I don't have that option

Comment: I've updated my question with a screenshot of my name and address options tab

Answer (score 0):

@Athul Vijayan that is only for customer registration form and it is not there anymore in the newer versions.

The Path is in Stores-> (Settings)Configuration -> Customers (tab) -> Customer Configuration -> Name and Address Options -> Show Prefix.

There is an image to show it.

[image: prefix]

Set them to no, and clear the cache.